# PHP/JSON - how to parsing before import to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

i want to save some items to database from json.

json source is here:

http://api.worldoftanks.eu/2.0/account/tanks/?application_id=d0a293dc77667c9328783d489c8cef73&account_id=500014703

I want to save the database only those values

"tank_id":
"battles":
"wins":

from each section

for checking JSON source i using this part of script, work fine

```
function readWotResponse($url, $isUrl = true)
{
  if ($isUrl && !ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
    throw new Exception('allow_url_fopen = Off');
  }

  $content = file_get_contents($url);
  if ($isUrl) {
   $status_code = substr($http_response_header[0], 9, 3);
  if ($status_code != 200) {
      throw new Exception('Got status code ' . $status_code . ' expected 200');
    }
  }

  $json = json_decode($content);
  if (!$json) {
    throw new Exception('Response contained an invalid JSON response');
  }

  if ($json->status != 'ok') {
    throw new Exception($json->status_code);
  }

  return $json;
}
```

for parsing i try

```
$tanks_id_url = "http://api.worldoftanks.eu/2.0/account/tanks/?application_id=d0a293dc77667c9328783d489c8cef73&account_id=500014703";

    try {
         $tjson = readWotResponse($tanks_id_url);
         print_r ($tjson) ;
       }
```

so and now i need help with good parsing to got good value.

when i use var_dump i got this

```
 object(stdClass)#1 (3) {   ["status"]=>   string(2) "ok"   ["count"]=>
 int(1)   ["data"]=>   object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
     ["500014703"]=>
     array(106) {
      [0]=>
       object(stdClass)#3 (6) {
         ["achievements"]=>
         object(stdClass)#4 (59) {
           ["medal_dumitru"]=>
           int(0) . . . . .
```

this part is problem for me

```
    **array(106) {
      [0]=>**
```

because when i want use

```
$value = $tjson->data->500014703->O->achievements->medal_dumitru;
```

i got error :-(

Comment: "to got good value"? huh?

Comment: how to parsing this JSON when I want save to the database only those values

"tank_id": "battles": "wins":

Comment: once you pass the json through json_decode(), you've got a native PHP data structure. `var_dump($tjson)` will show you the exact details of how to get at what you need.

Comment: accessing things in a PHP data structure is core/basic knowledge. If you can't handle it, then you need to step back and learn basic programming. We're here to help, not be your teachers